# Getting jquery dropdown change to toggle display of a different field based on val()

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to get the #org div to display only when the value "Friend" is selected in the dropdown (I've scrubbed the original value of three words with spaces, but didn't need it to identify where I work for these purposes, but I mention it in case the spaces would be an issue, which I doubt). And hide the display of #org when the value of the dropdown changes to anything other than "Friend." I thought this would work, and I've looked around at alternatives, but I hit a wall. I'd appreciate some extra eyeballs to help me see what I did wrong.

```js
$("#Affiliation").prop("selectedIndex", -1);

        $("#Affiliation").change(function () {
            var getVal = $(this).val();
            console.log(getVal);
            if (getVal == "Friend Of Peirce") {
                $("#org").attr("style", "display:block;");
            }
            else {
                $("#org").attr("style", "display:none;");
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <label>Affiliation</label>
    <div>
        <select id="Affiliation" name="Affiliation">
            <option value="Student">Student</option>
            <option value="Alumni">Alumni</option>
            <option value="Staff">Staff</option>
            <option value="Faculty">Faculty</option>
            <option value="Friend">Friend</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="org" style="display: none;">
    <label>Organization</label>
    <div>
        <input id="Organization" name="Organization" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

//edit (added getVal == "Friend") the single assignment was a typo

Comment: if (getVal === "Friend") {
                $("#org").show();
            }
            else {
                $("#org").hide();
            }

Comment: Dawood - add that as an answer and I'll mark it. Thanks. I knew it would be something simple.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in the if condition:

And use jQuery `hide` and `show` functions:

```
if (getVal === "Friend") {
    $("#org").show();
} else {
    $("#org").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong with the if condition

```js
$("#Affiliation").prop("selectedIndex", -1);

        $("#Affiliation").change(function () {
            var getVal = $(this).val();
            console.log(getVal);
            if (getVal == "Friend") {
                $("#org").attr("style", "display:block;");
            }
            else {
                $("#org").attr("style", "display:none;");
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <label>Affiliation</label>
    <div>
        <select id="Affiliation" name="Affiliation">
            <option value="Student">Student</option>
            <option value="Alumni">Alumni</option>
            <option value="Staff">Staff</option>
            <option value="Faculty">Faculty</option>
            <option value="Friend">Friend</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="org" style="display: none;">
    <label>Organization</label>
    <div>
        <input id="Organization" name="Organization" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
</div>
```